# v8 proxy ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, v8, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to use ES6 Proxy in v8 (version 4.6.85.31) but I'm getting `ReferenceError: Proxy is not defined`
(I'm using v8 from golang)

I also tried the same in node.js 5.1.0 with --harmony-proxies flag and it supports proxies(same v8 version)

But how can I use proxies directly in v8? do I need to compile it with some flags?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For those who got the same question, you can use

```
std::string flags("--harmony_proxies");
V8::SetFlagsFromString(flags.c_str(), flags.length());
```

Also see `node --v8-options` for complete list of v8 options, lot's of fun stuff!

for example I also needed `--expose_gc` flag to debug v8 garbage collection